# getting wrong value when dealing with time in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do some calculations on my excel sheet where I'm using macros , i'm dealing with time values.

```
 h2 = rg.Cells(i, 5) 'time value
 h1 = rg.Cells(i, 4) 'time value
 h3 = (TimeValue("23:59") - h1) + (h2 - TimeValue("23:59"))
```

the problem is for instance when `h1="20:00"` and `h2="07:55"` h3 should be `11:55` but it gives `12:05`

BTW `H1` is entrance time and `H2` is time out so h2 is in the next day and i'm trying to calculate the deference of time.

[image]

regards

Comment: What are you trying to get on h3?? are your variables declared as `Date` ?

Comment: yes variables are time values and it works perfectly except it get wrong values

Comment: it is giviing the wrong value it should be 11:55 not 12:05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because H2, as you point out, is a day after H1, you need to factor that in to your calculation.

So to calculate the difference between H1 and H2, 24 hours should be added to H2 first.

```
  h2  +  1dy
07:55 + 24:00 = 31:55

                  v
                         -h1
                31:55 - 20:00 = 11:55
```

A single day presented as time is `1` - as time is measured as a decimal fraction of a day.

So among many other ways of doing it, to get the above, your formula should be:

`h3 = (h2 + 1) - h1`

Comment: lets suppose that h1=12:00 and h2=12:00 of the next day using your formula would return 00 where it should return 24H

Comment: Well.. yes. Of course. If you want it to consider the date as well as the time, then you'll need to ensure that the cells contain the dates also. If both contain dates, then it's just a case of subtracting the earlier time from the later.

Comment: hmm , no there is no date but Im sure that h2 is in the next day so there is no way ?

Comment: Sorry, I see your reasoning now. The formula actually works as is and contains 1 whole day (24h), the problem is Excel will ***format*** it as TIME, and show only the TIME element. Re-format it to `[hh]:mm` instead of `hh:mm` and it will display `24:00`

Comment: With no time in the cells at all (keyed *or* displayed) and a formula of `= (h2 + 1) - h1` ? It works fine on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the correct answer is *minus* 11:05:00 but Excel doesn't handle negative time. Adding one day to minus 11:05::00 equals positive 12:05:00.